# How to find the max value in array without using sort cmd in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a `array=(4,2,8,9,1,0)` and I don't want to sort the array to find the highest number in the array because I need to get the index value of the highest number as it is, so I can use it for further reference.

**Expected output:**

```
 9 index value => 3
```

Can somebody help me to achieve this?

Comment: Since you're using arrays, I assume you're using Bash, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `sort`, you can use a simple loop in shell. Here is a sample `bash` code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=(4 2 8 9 1 0)

for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
   [[ -z $max ]] || (( ${array[i]} > $max )) && { max="${array[i]}"; maxind=$i; }
done

echo "max=$max, maxind=$maxind"
```

```
max=9, maxind=3
```

Answer (score 2):

Slight variation with a loop using the ternary conditional operator and no assumptions about range of values:

```
arr=(4 2 8 9 1 0)
max=${arr[0]}
maxIdx=0

for ((i = 1; i < ${#arr[@]}; ++i)); do
    maxIdx=$((arr[i] > max ? i : maxIdx))
    max=$((arr[i] > max ? arr[i] : max))
done

printf '%s index => values %s\n' "$maxIdx" "$max"
```

The only assumption is that array indices are contiguous. If they aren't, it becomes a little more complex:

```
arr=([1]=4 [3]=2 [5]=8 [7]=9 [9]=1 [11]=0)
indices=("${!arr[@]}")
maxIdx=${indices[0]}
max=${arr[maxIdx]}

for i in "${indices[@]:1}"; do
    ((arr[i] <= max)) && continue
    maxIdx=$i
    max=${arr[i]}
done

printf '%s index => values %s\n' "$maxIdx" "$max"
```

This first gets the indices into a separate array and sets the initial maximum to the value corresponding to the first index; then, it iterates over the indices, skipping the first one (the `:1` notation), checks if the current element is a new maximum, and if it is, stores the index and the maximum.

Comment: You don't even need that assumption; `for i in ${!arr[@]}; do`. The rest of your code takes a little tweaking to avoid the assumption that 0 is the smallest index.

Comment: I'd just check `arr[i] <=  max` once, and continue the loop if true. Then you can unconditionally update `maxIdx` and `max`.

Comment: @chepner But I wanted to use the ternary operator ;) Oh, I see you've removed your answer... I'll update this one again.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=(4 2 8 9 1 0)
paste <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}") <(seq 0 $((${#arr[@]} - 1)) ) | 
sort -k1,1 | 
tail -n1 |
sed 's/\t/ index value => /'
```

1. Print each array element on a newline with `printf`
2. Print array indexes with `seq`
3. Join both streams using `paste`
4. Numerically sort the lines using the first fields (ie. array value) `sort`
5. Print the last line `tail -n1`
6. The array value and result is separated by a tab. Substitute tab with the output string you want using `sed`. One could use ex. `cut -d, -f2` to get only the index or use `read a b <( ... )` to read the numbers into variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ export data=4,2,8,9,1,0
$ echo $data | perl -ne ' map{$i++; if($_>$x) {$x=$_;$id=$i} } split(","); print "max=$x", " index=",--${id},"\n" '
max=9 index=3
$
```